# Is the real part of a positive definite Hermitian matrix invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are real matrices such that $A=X+iY$ is Hermitian and positive definite. 
Does invertability of $A$ imply invertability of $X$?
Are all Hermitian positive definite matrices invertible?

Comment: To answer your second question: yes, all Hermitian positive definite matrices are invertible

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes.  In particular, it suffices to note that
$$
X = \frac 12A + \frac 12 \overline{A}
$$
is a sum of positive definite matrices.